# To what extent is MO usable with console browser, not supporting javascript and images?

Tags: support, user-interface

To what extent is MO usable with console browser, not supporting javascript and images? Say lynx/links/links2/elinks or something else?

I can live with javascript killed, but on some occasions when posting an answer captcha pops up and this bugs me, since answering is important.

Comment: You may get a better, or at least quicker, response to this on the main meta site.

Comment: @quid Do you mean meta.stackexchange.com?

Comment: An important related question is to what extent is MO (and more generally stackexchange sites) accessible to the blind.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. If you ask it is better to ask it in general for SE sites, and to add that you care specifically about a MathJax enabled site (MO). Anyway, the sites are all the same except for minor extensions (and some special casing for the huge SO).

Comment: Crossposted on meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277392/to-what-extent-is-se-usable-with-console-browser-not-supporting-javascript-and